# ppt presentation for postdoc position interview

Tags: postdocs, cv, interview

I have to prepare the presentation about my previous research experience for 20 minutes. I don't know what I should include, how big and how  much specific it should be

Comment: For one, use LaTeX's `beamer` document class to prepare academic presentations.

Comment: @JunaidAftab The OP mentioned a specific software package, and PowerPoint is perfectly acceptable. Advice like that is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: @Fomite I would go further than unnecessary and say that it is likely to be bad advice. Unless the OP already uses LaTeX then Beamer is probably the wrong choice (and if they do then they are less likely to need the advice).

Answer (score 1):

The first suggestion: Ask the people interviewing you. There's nothing wrong with asking if they would like a deep-dive or a broader research context, or what kind of audience you'll be drawing from.

In a more general sense, if you Google academic job talks, you should get a fair amount of advice. In general, the goal is to present your previous research in a coherent narrative, establishing who you are as a researcher so they can put you in context. Tell a story, and supplement it with the results of your research. As it's only 20 minutes, my guess is they are intending it to be fairly high level, rather than a very detailed exploration of any one result.

As for "How Big"...it should be 20 minutes, and as big or small as you can cover in that time.